# Changing CSS background dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background image of a fixed div when you hover over another div. I can change other properties but it won't let me override the image URL once set.

I want the product-preview's background-image to change dynamically when hovered over another div.

I tried combining multiple methods like hover, mouseenter+mouseleave and I also tried different css properties like background and background-image

**Javascript**

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

    //check for init
    window.alert("jQuery succesful");


    //basic

    //Poke Rice
    $("label.form-check-label[for=poke_rijst]").hover(function() {
        jQuery( ".product-preview" ).show();
        //afbeeldings URL
        var url = "http://i64.tinypic.com/ie12f9.jpg";
        jQuery(".product-preview").css("background-image",url);
    });

    //Poke Salad
    $("label.form-check-label[for=poke_salad]").hover(function() {
        jQuery( ".product-preview" ).show();
        //afbeeldings URL
        var url2 = "http://i65.tinypic.com/2zyv7dc.jpg";
        jQuery(".product-preview").css("background-image", url2);
    });

});
```

```css
.product-preview {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 230px;
  padding: 10px;
  right: 0;
background-image: url("http://i64.tinypic.com/ie12f9.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-preview"></div>
<label class="form-check-label" for="poke_rijst"><input type="radio" id="poke_rijst" name="ppom[fields][basis]" class="ppom-check-input" value="Poke Rijst" data-price="" data-optionid="poke_rijst" data-label="Poke Rijst" data-title="BASIS" data-onetime="" data-taxable="" data-without_tax="" data-data_name="basis"> <span class="ppom-label-radio">Poke Rijst</span></label>

<label class="form-check-label" for="poke_salad"><input type="radio" id="poke_salad" name="ppom[fields][basis]" class="ppom-check-input" value="Poke Salad" data-price="" data-optionid="poke_salad" data-label="Poke Salad" data-title="BASIS" data-onetime="" data-taxable="" data-without_tax="" data-data_name="basis"> <span class="ppom-label-radio">Poke Salad</span></label>
```

It works whenever no background-image is set yet. As soon as one of the functions placed a background-image, the other function will not override it. It does work when I set background-image, "none" on the second function.

Thanks in advance, I'm stil learning jQuery.

Here is a JDFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/buyfcr6q/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/buyfcr6q/

Answer (score 1):

The html was missing the elements you referenced (the `label`s) and the CSS background property was missing the "`url(  )`" bit. Also, the original html markup was invalid, as the string for the product-preview did not end with a quote, which made the javascript no longer work.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

    //basic

    //Poke Rice
    $(".form-check-label[for=poke_rijst]").hover(function() {
        jQuery( ".product-preview" ).show();
        //afbeeldings URL
        var url = "url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/300)";
        jQuery(".product-preview").css("background-image",url);
    });

    //Poke Salad
    $(".form-check-label[for=poke_salad]").hover(function() {
        jQuery( ".product-preview" ).show();
        //afbeeldings URL
        var url2 = "url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/200)";
        jQuery(".product-preview").css("background-image", url2);
    });

});
```

```css
.product-preview {
  display: none;
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.form-check-label {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.one {
  background: green;
}

.two {
  background: red;
}

div,label {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<label class="form-check-label one" for="poke_rijst"></label>
<label class="form-check-label two" for="poke_salad"></label>

<div class="product-preview"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. By just adding the url() around the image link, it already worked. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: Great, and if it helped you it would be nice if you accepted it as the answer. Great day to you too.